# uvc webcam upside down with google+ gtalk plugin

Tags: 11.04, google-chrome, webcam, google-talk

I've got google talk plugin installed and by default, my UVC webcam is upside down on Google+ Hangout video chat. How can I flip it over? I tried this and it didn't work:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin
google-chrome
```

This LD_PRELOAD trick works fine on skype. Cheese works well by default, probably because it's using v4l2.

Comment: Does it work in other applications like Cheese?

Comment: the LD_PRELOAD trick works fine on skype

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I forgot the ampersand at the end of the first line:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin &
google-chrome
```

It now works. Still flipped if I don't call the first line before I call my browser.